# Fitting curves in Jupyter Notebook without using the fit function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-fitting

For a task for school, I have to write my own fit function by using the least squares method. The problem is I don't know how to do that, specifically I don't know how to minimize my function to calculate my fit parameters.The problem here is also that my fit function is not linear, so my book says I have to try guess some values for my fit parameters and then minimize my function. But still I don't know how do to that. The code that you can find below is my code right now, I got it from somebody but I don't understand what it does so :).

Thanks in advance!

```
def fit(x,mu,gamma,back,A):
   return A*(gamma/((x-mu)**2+gamma**2))+back 
def Ls_rechte(y): 
   Ls = 0
   for i in range(len(Positie)):
       Ls = Ls + (Intensiteit[i]- fit(Positie[i],y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3]))**2/(FoutI[i]**2)
       return Ls
nu = len(Positie)-4
mini = minimize(Ls_rechte,(150,0,100,1))
display(mini)
```